# Error installing keras with pip in Python2.7 (Windows 7): numpy not found

Tags: python, python-2.7, numpy, keras

I'm totally new using Python and I have to learn quickly because of my job. I have downloaded Python2.7.13 (and also the pip package. My next step was:

```
C:\Python27\pip install keras
```

And it finished saying that theano and anaconda2 were installed to and also was fine. 
The problem came when I tried the following line:

```
C:\Python27\python
>>>from keras.models import Sequential
```

And I get the following message (after others that don't give error):

```
ImportError: No module named numpy
```

The fact is that I got out of python and try pip install numpy and it says that I have already have numpy installed and show me in which folder I have it. So I go to that folder and try:

```
C:\users\maca\anaconda2\lib\site-packages\numpy\python setup.py install
```

And that returns:

```
This is the wrong setup.py file to run
```

I'm totally new so I'm very lost about what my next step should be and how to fix it, 'cause I'm not familiarized with Python. I would thank any understandable help. 
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you have vanilla python installed in `C:\Python27\` and Anaconda installed in `C:\Users\Maca\Anaconda2`. These are *different*. Anaconda is *not an add-on* to python, it *is* a distribution of python. Anaconda will have the math prerequisites, vanilla will not. You can install Keras on vanilla (it's hard), but it sounds like you want to use Anaconda. Then use *only* anaconda. Run:

```
activate root
```

You should then be using Anaconda and you can run:

```
pip install keras
```

Also, keras works on top of a backend so make sure you either have theano (`pip install theano`) or [tensorflow](https://www.tensorflow.org/).
Then, *in the same console window*, using Anaconda, run `python` and type `from keras.models import Sequential`. It should work.

From then on, you can access anaconda (as long as it was set up with this command enabled) with `activate root`. This will set `python` and related arguments to refer to *Anaconda* rather than the default `C:\Python27`.

EDIT: If in the future you are planning to use only anaconda, you can delete `C:\Python27` from your path or even add Anaconda to it. To add anaconda to you path, look up `environment variables` in the start menu, go to the system environment variables, and find `PATH`. If you haven't uninstalled Python27 yet you'll need to remove `C:\Python27\` from that path, and then you can add `C:\Users\Maca\Anaconda2` anywhere (probably towards the end depending on how often you use python and how cluttered your path is).

Comment: Thanks, I did what you said and you were right, I have to use Anaconda, it worked. Also I found another problem with the backend keras uses (I didn't have tensor flow installed) but I have already solve it.

Comment: Ok thanks, glad it worked out! The flexible backend is a great feature of Keras, since I use theano. I'll update my answer because I forgot to include that, just for anyone who stops by. Also, if this answered your question could you please just mark it as such so people don't keep trying to answer (plus karma for me -_-) Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You are already using Anaconda Python distribution so you should use conda package manager for installing keras: run `conda install keras` in your terminal. This will install keras and all the dependencies.